# The relation between a matrix being invertible and its row reduced form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
 a & b\\
 c & d
\end{pmatrix}.$ Prove using elementary row operations that $A$ is invertible iff $ad - bc \neq 0.$

And I reached the following matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
 a & b\\
 0 & ad - bc
\end{pmatrix}.$

after row-reducing $A.$ but then I do not know the relation between a matrix being invertible and its row reduced form. Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: I would suggest consulting a textbook for a more full explanation, but a square matrix is invertible if and only if its reduced row-echelon form doesn't have any row of all zeroes.

Comment: Do you suggest a specific textbook speaking about this? @KenanskiBowspleefi

Comment: I'm not familiar with many textbooks, and it probably depends on what sort of approach you're taking. I learned from Shifrin and Adams, *Linear Algebra: A Geometric Approach* for my first course, but there are many others out there as well. (I believe this one I mentioned is available as a free pdf if you search thoroughly enough...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $ad-bc\neq 0$. This implies either $a$ or $c$ must be nonzero. Assume without loss $a\neq 0$ and let's do a few more row operations from where you left off:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 a & b\\
 0 & ad - bc
\end{pmatrix} \overset{\small R1'=(ad-bc)*R1-b*R2}{\longrightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}
 a(ad-bc) & 0\\
 0 & ad - bc
\end{pmatrix} \underset{\overset{\small R2'=R2/(ad-bc)}{\longrightarrow}}{\overset{\small R1'=R1/(a(ad-bc))}{\longrightarrow}}\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0\\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}. $$

If $a=0,c\neq 0$, one could first swap the rows of the original matrix so that we start with $$\begin{pmatrix}
 c & d\\
 a & b
\end{pmatrix}$$

so that $c$ plays the role of $a$ and then rinse and repeat the same steps to get the identity matrix.

---

The bottom line is this: a matrix is invertible if and only if it is row equivalent to the identity matrix. This is one of the many *many* equivalent characterizations of invertibility in the [invertible matrix theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html).